# Standard/RFC for HTTP sessions?

Tags: http, web, session

HTTP as a protocol is stateless. RFC 2965 defines the state mechanism for HTTP (cookies), but then there is also the concept of HTTP sessions. Cookies are used for tracking the user session (using session ids), but the actual content of the session variables are stored on the server. Languages such as JSP, ASP and PHP include a session mechanism for maintaining HTTP sessions.

I was wondering, is there an RFC or standard that defines how HTTP sessions should be implemented? After all, JSP, ASP and PHP all implement HTTP sessions in pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 3):

The original RFC for cookies is 2109 which was superseded by 2965 which in its turn was superseded by RFC6265. RFC6265 talks about sessions and session identifiers.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265

Comment: Great to see that you've found the answer! It's possible to mark your own answer as correct after 24h, it will help keep SU clean.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6896 which gives rather more detail than RFC6265's "Servers SHOULD encrypt and sign the contents of cookies (using whatever format the server desires)"

Some more information on using cookies for secure sessions:
http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6062/pdf/imm6062.pdf
http://nordsecmob.aalto.fi/en/publications/theses_2011/thesis_nazmul.pdf
[http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sjm217/papers/protocols08cookies.pdf](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Esjm217/papers/protocols08cookies.pdf)